# window function to identify what values are for a key over month

Tags: postgresql

I have data that looks like this:

```
product | month | purchased
a           jan     online  
a           jan     instore
b           jan     online
c           jan     instore
```

what I want to do is identify how the product was purchased in a given month in the same result set like this:

```
product | month | purchased | method
a           jan     online      online-instore
a           jan     instore     online-instore
b           jan     online      online
c           jan     instore     instore
```

I was wondering if there was a way to write a window query that could do this instead of writing a separate query and then joining that back to the result set.

Answer (score 0):

`MIN/MAX` windows functions can be used:

```
SELECT product, month, purchased,
       CASE max( purchased ) OVER (partition by product, month )
       WHEN min( purchased ) OVER (partition by product, month )
       THEN min( purchased ) OVER (partition by product, month )
       ELSE max( purchased ) OVER (partition by product, month )
            || '-' ||
            min( purchased ) OVER (partition by product, month )
       END As method
FROM Table
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select
  product, month,
  array_agg(purchased) over (partition by product, month) as method
from
  your_table
group by
  product, month, purchased;
```

If you want exactly `method1-method2-...` result then change `array_agg(purchased)` to `string_agg(purchased, '-')`